# How do I install gradle on Windows 10?

Tags: gradle

I tried some ways with the path thing, but it did not work. When I edit the path in the System variables it opens up all the paths, not like in tutorials, where I should just put the `;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin` at the end.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 28):

Download Gradle and unzip it to where you want it installed.

Then in Windows Search, search for "System" and then select: System (Control Panel)

Click the Advanced system settings link.

Click Environment Variables

Then click New button under *user variable* and add `GRADLE_HOME` to variable name and path pointing to the root directory of unpacked files from the Gradle to variable value.

[image: GRADLE_HOME]

In *System variable* section select *Path* and then click the Edit button.
In next window click New button and add path pointing to the bin directory of unpacked files from the Gradle.

[image: Edit path variabl]

Comment: Do you need the GRADLE_HOME variable if you don't use it in your PATH variable?

Comment: no need for GRADLE_HOME variable if you're not going to use it. adding it to System variable Path should make it work.

Answer (score 10):

If you are window user then `Scoop` will be the best option to installs the tools you know and love. [Scoop](http://scoop.sh/) is simply a command line installer.

simply run this command`scoop install gradle`

But first you need to install scoop using powershell command

```
iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
```

**Note:** if you get an error you might need to change the execution policy (i.e. enable Powershell) with following command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 7):

`choco install gradle` in shell/cmd.
of course, you gotta install the chocolatey first from [here](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation)

> Chocolatey - the package manager for Windows.

Comment: I keep forgetting about this wonderfull software manager. It makes all pains go away :)
Thanks man!

Answer (score 6):

In case you're here and none of these answers "helped", try restarting the shell program.
I just spent more than an hour and I just had to restart my console window to do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

[Download](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/) Gradle and unzip it to where you want it installed. Then open your USER variables window for your user (similar to what you show) and create a `GRADLE_HOME` variable with a path pointing to the root directory of your downloaded Gradle distribution. Then add it to the `PATH` in your USER variables with something like:

```
%PATH%;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin
```

Notice that I have prepended the existing PATH variable onto the new one. You don't want to remove what's already there. Also, your image shows something else added to the path. You will want to add that on to the line above, something like:

```
%PATH%;%YOUR_OTHER_STUFF%;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin
```

So that it won't be lost either.

This is what I have done on Windows for years. Other options are to use something like http://sdkman.io/; however, that requires extra work on Windows since it's really meant for OSes with a real terminal.