# Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle

I develop a hybrid app usin cordova. While I was trying to build the android verion of my App, i got this error:

Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio.

..although Android Studio is already installed and everything worked so far.

Does anybody know the reason for this issue?

Comment: Can you `cat` your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
`?

Comment: The content of gradle-wrapper.properties looks like this: distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Comment: And you should also show your os

Comment: My OS is Windows 7

Comment: In my opinion,you have not set `gradle`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856932/how-do-i-install-gradle-on-windows-10 may help you.

Comment: Okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the file: \cordova\lib\check_reqs.js
When cordova checks the location of graddle is doing this: var androidPath = path.join(process.env['ProgramFiles'], 'Android') + '/';

If you don't have installed in certain location, cordova can't find the file.
So... edit tcheck_reqs.js and do this (i'm using Windows 10 and cordova 7.0.1):

```
return 'C:\\Android\\sdk\\gradle\\gradle-3.2\\bin\\gradle';

if (androidStudioPath !== null && fs.existsSync(androidStudioPath)) {
    var dirs = fs.readdirSync(androidStudioPath);
    if(dirs[0].split('-')[0] == 'gradle') {
        return path.join(androidStudioPath, dirs[0], 'bin', 'gradle');
    }

} else {
    //OK, let's try to check for Gradle!
    return forgivingWhichSync('gradle');
}
```

It's not a real fix, but if you are sure of your gradle location it will be fine, hope cordova fix this.

Comment: I also solved the problem in another way: 
I moved all files which were saved on storage D: to location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\Android Studio". 
Those were:
"bin | gradle | jre | lib | license | plugins | build.txt | LICENSE.txt | NOTICE.txt and uninstall.exe"
Now, if I run "cordova build android" it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bubuko.com/infodetail-2108699.html，
its about your cordova version;