# 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command when trying to build jar file

Tags: java, gradle, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, build.gradle

I am trying to create a jar file so I can upload my code on aws however when I type in /gradle bootJar I get a gradle not recognized error. I tried to install gradle but nothing is working. This is the error I get below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weqiY.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you add the gradle /bin dir to your PATH system env?

Comment: windows gradle installation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856932/how-do-i-install-gradle-on-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

From the gradle task you're trying to run, I assume that you that you're running a spring boot project.

Also from your screenshot, I can see that you don't have gradle installed in your machine. But that should not be an issue since spring boot projects normally include a gradle wrapper.

Make sure that you have the gradle folder and `gradlew.bat` file in the root folder of your project. In the cmd window, cd to the project location and run command `gradlew bootJar`.

Remember to use `gradlew.bat`, not `gradle`.